# using ajaxComplete with drupal quicktabs

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I am trying to use `.ajaxComplete()` on my quicktabs but i cant seem to get it to hit. Would anyone have any ideas?

```
jQuery('#quicktabs-tab-find_a_doctor-1').click(function(){
  console.log('CLICKED');
  jQuery('#quicktabs-tab-find_a_doctor-1').css({
      "float":"left",
      "padding-right":"5px"
    });
  jQuery('#quicktabs-tab-find_a_doctor-1').parent().append('<div id="loading-icon"><img src="sites/all/themes/contributed/holyspirit/images/4.gif" /></div>');

  //jQuery('#loading-icon').ajaxComplete(function(){
     // jQuery(this).hide();
    //});

  Drupal.behaviors.LoadingIcon = {
    attach: function() {  
      jQuery('#loading-icon').ajaxComplete(function() {
        jQuery(this).hide();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I have tried both ideas, but i still cant get it to hit. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Of course after posting on here I was able to figure out my mistake.

```
jQuery('#quicktabs-tab-find_a_doctor-1').click(function(){

  // Making room for loading icon
  jQuery('#quicktabs-tab-find_a_doctor-1').css({
      "float":"left",
      "padding-right":"5px"
    });

  // Adding the loading icon to tab
  jQuery('#quicktabs-tab-find_a_doctor-1').parent().append('<div id="loading-icon"><img src="sites/all/themes/contributed/holyspirit/images/4.gif" /></div>');

  // Once ajax is complete remove loading icon from page
  (function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.LoadingIcon = {
      attach: function() {  
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
          $('#loading-icon').remove();
          $('#quicktabs-tab-find_a_doctor-1').css({
            "padding-right":"0px"
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }(jQuery));
});
```

According to http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/
You need to attach the `.autoComplete()` onto the document as stated right here:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document.

Comment: a behavior should not be defined in a click event ! your mixing jQuery and $, your code should look like this `(function($) { Drupal.behaviors.LoadingIcon = {} $('#quicktabs-tab-find_a_doctor-1').click(); })(jQuery));`